# Xcode 5.0.2 Crashes on Running Simple Code

Tags: xcode5

I have made simple code that builds in XCode. When I place the play/run button in the upper left corner I receive the error below this paragraph. I have tried the following things: Downloading and running XCode 5.0 instead. Disabling source control in Preferences. Re-installing iTunes. None have worked.

```
Process:         Xcode [2603]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0.2 (3335.32)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3335032000000000~4
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 106632651
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [288]
Responsible:     Xcode [2603]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-12-24 21:18:17.467 -1000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  EA8A0ADD-1FEE-BE0F-43E2-EDD5C4C34AE3

Sleep/Wake UUID: 6C4103F6-A3F4-48D0-9935-E0F2C50A2CFE

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
Sending performRunAction: to <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7fd501cea240> from <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7fd501cea240>
ProductBuildVersion: 5A3005
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Error getting value for key 'workerClass' of extension 'Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Debugger.LLDB' in plug-in 'com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB'
UserInfo: {
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 \"Loading a plug-in failed.\" UserInfo=0x7fd508dbf330 {DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in \U201ccom.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB\U201d at path \U201c/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin\U201d could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd508eb8ef0 \"The bundle \U201cDebuggerLLDB\U201d couldn\U2019t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.\"}";
}
Hints: 
  0: Sending performRunAction: to <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7fd501cea240> from <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7fd501cea240>
  1: Sending performAction: to <DVTDelayedMenuButtonCell: 0x7fd501cbaa40> from <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7fd501cea240>
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff85e1d404 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x000000010f827d73 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff86fbce75 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x000000010f7b5cd2 -[DVTExtension valueForKey:] (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x0000000114262109 -[DBGLLDBDebugLocalService operationWorkerWithLaunchSession:error:] (in DebuggerLLDBService)
  5  0x000000011749fe17 -[IDERuniPhoneSimulatorService operationWorkerWithLaunchSession:error:] (in IDEiOSSupportCore)
  6  0x000000011027ad49 -[IDERunDestination runWorkerForLaunchSession:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
  7  0x000000011027aa74 -[IDERunDestination runOperationForLaunchSession:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
  8  0x00000001102e2fee -[IDELaunchSchemeAction runOperationForExecutionEnvironment:withBuildOperation:buildParameters:buildableProductDirectories:schemeActionRecord:outError:actionCallbackBlock:] (in IDEFoundation)
  9  0x00000001102d6f5b -[IDEScheme _executionOperationForExecutionEnvironment:build:onlyBuild:buildPurpose:buildCommand:schemeCommand:title:overridingProperties:destination:buildLog:filePath:overridingBuildConfiguration:restorePersistedBuildResults:invocationRecord:overridingTestingSpecifiers:error:actionCallbackBlock:] (in IDEFoundation)
 10  0x00000001102d434d -[IDEScheme runWithExecutionContext:buildIfNeeded:onlyBuild:destination:overridingProperties:commandName:invocationRecord:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 11  0x0000000110a585d4 -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _actuallyPerformSchemeTask:onScheme:runDestination:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:overridingTestingSpecifiers:invocationRecord:completionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 12  0x0000000110a5bcd7 __175-[IDEWorkspaceTabController _performSchemeTask:onScheme:runDestination:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:overridingTestingSpecifiers:invocationRecord:completionBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 13  0x0000000110a5bafc -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _performSchemeTask:onScheme:runDestination:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:overridingTestingSpecifiers:invocationRecord:completionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 14  0x0000000110a5c797 __185-[IDEWorkspaceTabController _performDebuggableSchemeTask:onScheme:runDestination:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:overridingTestingSpecifiers:invocationRecord:completionBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 15  0x0000000110a5cd02 -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _forceSwitchToLLDBIfNecessary:preAlertHandler:completionHandler:] (in IDEKit)
 16  0x0000000111ea6264 -[DVTDeveloperModeAlertHelper _askToEnableDeveloperModeIfNecessary] (in DVTDeveloperModeHelper)
 17  0x0000000110a5c657 -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _performDebuggableSchemeTask:onScheme:runDestination:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:overridingTestingSpecifiers:invocationRecord:completionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 18  0x0000000110a5d2a8 -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _runScheme:runDestination:invocationRecord:] (in IDEKit)
 19  0x00000001109a373b -[IDEWorkspaceTabController runActiveRunContext:] (in IDEKit)
 20  0x0000000110ab61b1 -[IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton performRunAction:] (in IDEKit)
 21  0x00007fff850743d0 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 22  0x000000010ff08aff __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
 23  0x000000010f827ab1 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 24  0x000000010fd3a5ba -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 25  0x000000010fefd220 -[DVTDelayedMenuButtonCell performAction:] (in DVTKit)
 26  0x00007fff850743d0 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 27  0x000000010ff08aff __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
 28  0x000000010f827ab1 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 29  0x000000010fd3a5ba -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 30  0x000000010fe05a74 -[DVTDelayedMenuButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in DVTKit)
 31  0x00007fff850d91fd -[NSControl mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
 32  0x000000010fe21832 -[DVTMainStatusAwareButton mouseDown:] (in DVTKit)
 33  0x000000010fe217c3 -[DVTRolloverTrackingButton mouseDown:] (in DVTKit)
 34  0x00007fff8505ad08 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 35  0x00007fff84ff9744 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 36  0x000000011089d83b -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 37  0x00007fff84e49a29 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 38  0x00007fff84e34803 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 39  0x00007fff900245fd start (in libdyld.dylib)
 40  0x0000000000000001

abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a77b866 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff82d9b35c pthread_kill + 92
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8cc5ebba abort + 125
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000110a9a7af +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:reason:] + 775
4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000110a9b9fd -[IDEAssertionHandler handleUncaughtException:] + 919
5   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000110a9baa8 IDEHandleUncaughtException + 77
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84e49ad8 -[NSApplication run] + 821
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84e34803 NSApplicationMain + 940
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff900245fd start + 1
```

Comment: I would suspect something got corrupted either in Xcode's installation or your preferences.  A quick test is to log into a different account on your computer (create one if necessary) and see if Xcode works there.  If it works, the problem is in your ~/Library; if not, it's the application.

Comment: I have logged into a different account and Xcode still fails. However, it is very peculiar to me that something got corrupted in Xcode's installation because I have re-installed xCode twice. What else could be the problem here? @PhillipMills

Comment: same problem also just happened to me!

Answer (score 3):

I was the same and the problem is that it did not properly install python 2

Comment: It was python for me as well. I was installing it using brew but when i installed from https://www.python.org/downloads/ it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a known issue.  Try changing your compiler to GDB until they issue a fix for it.

Comment: Xcode 5 does not support use of the LLVM-GCC compiler and the GDB debugger. @AMayes